# How do I identify the cause of repeated (unexpected) `repartition-split-repartition-merge` tasks?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

In the task graph that Dask outputs via `ddf.visualize()`, I see many `*-repartition-split-repartition-merge` tasks, where `*` could be `join`, `rename` or some other task that I recognise from my application.

I am attempting to identify where these are coming from, whether they are having a performance impact (I imagine constantly repartitioning/splitting/merging data has costs, without aiding my computational aims directly), and, if so, how I can remove them.

They appear to dominate the compute time in the `performance_report` provided by `distributed`.

Looking at the Dask source code, I can see in the `dask.dataframe.core` source that the `DataFrame` method `repartition` puts these values into the `HighLevelGraph`:

```
[...]
        tmp = "repartition-split-" + token
        out = "repartition-merge-" + token
        dsk = repartition_divisions(
            df.divisions, divisions, df._name, tmp, out, force=force
        )
        graph = HighLevelGraph.from_collections(out, dsk, dependencies=[df])
        return new_dd_object(graph, out, df._meta, divisions)
[...]
```

Given that I am not specifically asking Dask to repartition in my application, how can I find out what is triggering this?

I've tried setting breakpoints within this bit of Dask code but I don't seem to hit it.

Comment: Aaaaah wait, joining along an index will involve ensuring the partitions/divisions are aligned. So in order to do a join, it has to `repartition-split` the dataframe, then do the join, before `repartition-merge`ing them back to the original divisions?

Comment: I think the bits before `repartition-split-repartition-merge` are red herrings. The `split-merge` always seem to occur in a node before a `join` or `concat`, so its basically Dask attempting to align partitions/divisions while preparing to combine dataframes.

Comment: I'm glad that you found your answer.  Nice detective work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, it was because my application handles many different dataframes, and merges them at the end of its execution.

As part of this merging, Dask needs to align the divisions/partitions, and does this via the `DataFrame.repartition()` method. In that method, it looks like at least two distinct tasks are created - `repartition-split` (taking on partition and breaking it up in to `n` others) and `repartition-merge` (joining `m` partitions into one).